# Jenkins job DSL - javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.GitParamContext.useRepository()

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl

I am trying to use Jenkins DSL groovy to create Jenkins job. The method I am using for Git Parameter, few of the parameters are not recognized with following errors.

> No signature of method:
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.GitParamContext.selectedValue() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [NONE]
>
> No signature of method:
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.GitParamContext.useRepository() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

I cannot find much help online and found https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/helpers/GitParamContext.groovy and it seems jenkins currently support just
String description
String type = 'TAG'
String branch
String tagFilter
String sortMode = 'NONE'
String defaultValue

I need to use selectedValue() and useRepository() to use default selected value and provide specific github repo url.
I have multiple scm in my jenkins job.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 Options available under Job->Parameters.[image]
Inorder to use selectedValue and useRepository , use the gitparameterdefinition member instead of gitparam